# Is it possible to simulate a browser with AWS lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

Is it possible to create an aws lambda function that would act as a browser accessing a website (without auth) reading its html and executing its js ?

Comment: Notice that lambda functions can run for maximum of 5 minutes.

Comment: I use CasperJS and it works great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup a headless browser such as [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) but it won't be straightforward and cost effective with Lambda since,

- Need to find a compiled set of binaries running on top of Amazon Linux (Which Lambda runs on).
- Requires to load the binaries at each execution which will add an overhead for the Lambda function start and also increases the billing time.

I would recommend to run an EC2 instance for this. Even a Nano Instance or a docker container is fine to start with.

Comment: *"Requires to load the binaries at each execution"* Why?  Could you not just start it up and leave it running with `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false` and then trigger it to navigate to a new page on each subsequent invocation for the container? Or is there something about the design of PhantomJS that would prevent this?  You can compile your own binaries for Amazon Linux with the Lambda environment ancestor AMI, so is this unusually difficult or unwieldy?  (note, the downvote seems unjustified and is not mine.)

Comment: Hi @Michael. I used PhantomJS for webpage image snaphot and did an evaluation for Lambda and Docker. My point regarding loading of the binaries is that, PhanthomJS binaries are large enough for a Lambda that slows down the cold start and also I have experienced the need to allocate more memory that will add cost for the Lambda. My point is using an EC2 instance or docker container(long running) can become more efficient for this.

Comment: In addition regarding the binaries it can be compiled or need to find the suitable ones. This I found difficult few years back but now hope more support is available. Have you tried the context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop set to false before? It seems interesting if it works.

Comment: So it sounds like you're saying this is a theoretically viable solution but Lambda may not be the most desirable environment in which to use it.

Comment: That was my experiance when I tried this in 2015. Things might have changed by now and I'm happy to hear if there are alternative approaches using PhanthomJS with Lambda.

Comment: I use `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false` for other purposes, like keeping database connections open or background `child_process` running between invocations to avoid respawning it.  Without it, the Lambda function will not return after the callback is called, if the event loop still has things it needs to watch.  It may be useful for something like this, as well... I haven't used PhantomJS, so I don't know the implications of it.